# Vue: Filter returns an array, how to get the first element

Tags: vue.js

Lets say I have a custom filter cf.js that needs to return multiple values in an array like this:

```
export default (value) => {
 var a = 5
 var b = 3

 return [a, b]
}
```

In my vue file, how can I display only the first element? I thought something like below would work but they do not

```
{{ myvar | cf[0] }} or {{ (myvar | cf)[0] }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're limited by the filter syntax in the Vue template, so what you tried won't work.

A filter doesn't make sense in the example you've given since it doesn't make use of the argument.

But anyway, to answer your question, two options come to mind:

**1. Define another filter to get the first element**

```vue
{{ myvar | cf | first }}
```

```es6
export default function first(value) {
  return value[0]
}
```

**2. Call the filter function manually**

This will allow you to do what you want with the filter result since you're just calling it as if it were any other function.

```es6
{{ $options.filters.cf(myvar)[0] }}
```

Comment: I knew the first one, I was looking for the 2nd one.